# PHP / MYSQL troubleshoot I can't see whats wrong

Tags: php, mysql, variables

This is me experimenting with PHP I'm new to it. I'm trying to see if a given username is already found in a mysql database here is my current code:

```
<?php
// $uname is the username I am trying to see if is the database
$uname = "djm";
//server info
$servuser = "root";
$servpass = "";
$db = "toob";
$server = "127.0.0.1";
//connecting to server
$db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $servuser, $servpass);
$db_found = mysql_select_db("toob", $db_handle);

//checking to see if ocnnected
if ($db_found) {
    print("connected");

//defining my sql statement
    $sql = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = $uname";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);


    if ($result) {
        print("Yes");
    } else {
        print("No");
    }
} else {
    print("Can't connect to server");
}
```

I always prints no, i have managed to make to print yes by replacing :

```
$sql="SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = $uname";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
```

with

```
$sql="SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = 'djm'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

However i need if to work off variables.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Instead of printing `'no'`, try `print(mysql_error());`, you'll see any SQL errors.  This will help you much more than `'no'` will.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

replace this

```
 if ($result)
```

with

```
 if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

You're missing the quotes:

It's a good idea to escape the input before passing them as a mysql query.
Try:

```
$sql = "SELECT username FROM users 
WHERE username = '". mysql_real_escape_string($uname)."'";
```

Currently, it will say "yes" if the query is executed successfully. Replace `if ($result)` with `if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)` if you're trying to check if the record exists.

Unrelated: [**`mysql_*`**](http://php.net/mysql) functions are now deprecated, and I'd suggest switching to `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: Cheers, I copied and pasted it bu it now says yes to any value I put in $uname

Comment: @user2621630, yes, that's expected. Currently, it will say "yes" if the query is executed successfully. Replace `if ($result)` with `if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)` if you're trying to check if the record exists.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should escape all user input:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($uname);
```

then you need to wrap SQL values in quotes:

```
$sql="SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
```

A bit away from your question; something on mysql referenced from [php's website](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php): "This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future."

You would be better off using [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqli.php)

Comment: Thanks I did your suggestion but it now says yes to any value that I use for $uname

Comment: No need to escape it since it's not a user input, the value is hardcoded in the script...1st line of code...but if you take it from $_GET or $_POST in the final script, you need to escape it

Comment: okay fabien, I've taken the escape out any other suggestions to get it working...